# Using two body in same CSS file

Tags: css

I have a CSS like below,

```
@media screen {
    .page{}
}
@media print {
    .page {}
}


body
{
    background-color:#ffffe0;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

select
{
    font-size     : 24pt; font-family: 'MS UI Gothic' ; 
}
```

I want to use the same CSS but only the values inside the body should be changed. The values are

```
body
{
    background-color:#ffffe0;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

I tried adding a new class like this. Is this right ? Or how we can use two different body for different classes. Please anybody tell me.

I tried like this

```
@media screen {
        .page{}
    }
    @media print {
        .page {}
    }


    body
    {
        background-color:#ffffe0;
        margin-left:20px;
        margin-top:50px;
        margin-bottom:50px;
    }

    select
    {
        font-size     : 24pt; font-family: 'MS UI Gothic' ; 
    }

@media screen2 {
        .page2{}
    }
    @media print2 {
        .page2 {}
    }


    body
    {
        background-color:#ffffe0;
        margin-left:20px;
        margin-top:50px;
        margin-bottom:50px;
    }

    select
    {
        font-size     : 24pt; font-family: 'MS UI Gothic' ; 
    }
```

But every time it is taking only the first body only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the `body` selectors, they both apply to the same element, so only one can be used. If you want to change the style of body, change the existing selector's properties. If you want to switch between the two based on some logic, give the `<body>` element an ID or class and add that to the selectors so you can choose which one will apply.

ALso, screen2 and print2 aren't valid media selectors.

Comment: Bit confused. I am trying to access this CSS using the class name page. If you don't mind could you please elaborate it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "class name page"? Are you using `<body class="page">`? If so, you can change your css to `body.page {` to affect only pages where you have `body` with `class=page`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the first bit.
As @Adrian said, you can only have one body element for a page.
Secondly, @media and @print corresponds to normal screens (such as desktop, laptop, and such) and prints (for examples, when you click on the print button) respectively.
So, what you need to do is simple. Either put the body tag outside all the other media queries.

```
body {
background-color:#ffffe0;
margin-left:20px;
margin-top:50px;
margin-bottom:50px;
}

@media screen {
.page{}

rest of your styles and classes...

}
@media print {
body {
background-color:#ffffe0;
margin-left:5px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
}
.page {}

rest of your styles and classes...

}
and so on...
```

or

do this...

```
@media screen {
body {
background-color:#ffffe0;
margin-left:20px;
margin-top:50px;
margin-bottom:50px;
}
.page{}
}
@media print {
body {
background-color:#ffffe0;
margin-left:5px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
}
.page {}
}
```

However, you should note that the print type css will only visible while you take a print out. It will not be visible on the main site display.